# How to remove everything before certain character in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm new to python and struggle with a certain task:

I have a String that could have anything in it, but it always "ends" the same.
It can be just a Filename, a complete path, or just a random string, ending with a Version Number.

Example:

```
C:\Users\abc\Desktop\string-anotherstring-15.1R7-S8.1
string-anotherstring-15.1R7-S8.1
string-anotherstring.andanother-15.1R7-S8.1
```

What always is the same (looking from the end) is that if you reach the second dot and go 2 characters in front of it, you always match the part that I'm interested in.
Cutting everything after a certain string was "easy," and I solved it myself - that's why the string ends with the version now :)

Is there a way to tell python, "look for the second dot from behind the string and go 2 in front of it and delete everything in front of that so that I get the Version as a string?

Happy for any pointers in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: So - out of 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\string-anotherstring-15.1R7-S8.1' are you looking for S8.1?

Comment: use str.rsplit() and see the output then slice the required value (-2)

Comment: I'm looking for 15.1R7-S8.1

How do I tell rsplit to "count" from behind and only use the second "."? Else it will produce extremely weird outputs...

Comment: ALso, If i "split" with the dot, the dot is lost - however, it's part of the Software version.

Comment: Why don't you try it on interpretor to see the outputs? rplit will split from right side. Use negative numbers to use values from right side.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not always the same number of chars, so counting from behind is not an option :(

Comment: Don't think  in terms of character, but groups which you get after splitting by separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand this correctly, there are two ways to do this that come to mind:

Including both, since I might not understand this correctly, and for completeness reasons. I think the split/parts solution is cleaner, particularly when the 'certain character' is a dot.

```
>>> msg = r'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\string-anotherstring-15.1R7-S8.1'

>>> re.search(r'.*(..\..*)', msg).group(1)
'S8.1'

>>> parts = msg.split('.')
>>> ".".join((parts[-2][-2:], parts[-1]))
'S8.1'
```

Comment: Thanks.
I modified it to get the complete Version string:

".".join((parts[-3][-2:], parts[-2], parts[-1]))

This way, I always get the full Version :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the version number, can you use the hyphen (-) to split the string? Or do you need to depend on the dots only?

Please see below use of [rsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) and [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) which can help you.

```
>>> a = 'string-anotherstring.andanother-15.1R7-S8.1'
>>> a.rsplit('-')
['string', 'anotherstring.andanother', '15.1R7', 'S8.1']
>>> a.rsplit('-')[-2:] #Get everything from second last to the end
['15.1R7', 'S8.1']
>>> '-'.join(a.rsplit('-')[-2:]) #Get everything from second last to the end, and join them with a hyphen
'15.1R7-S8.1'
>>>
```

For using dots, use the same way

```
>>> a
'string-anotherstring.andanother-15.1R7-S8.1'
>>> data = a.rsplit('.')
>>> [data[-3][-2:]]
['15']
>>> [data[-3][-2:]] + data[-2:]
['15', '1R7-S8', '1']
>>> '.'.join([data[-3][-2:]] + data[-2:])
'15.1R7-S8.1'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a regex from the end mark of a line using the anchor `$`.

Using your own description, use the regex:

```
(\d\d\.[^.]*)\.[^.]*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ChcXeI/1/)

If you want the last characters from the end included, just move the capturing parenthesis:

```
(\d\d\.[^.]*\.[^.]*)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ChcXeI/2)

Explanation:

```
(\d\d\.[^.]*\.[^.]*)$

 ^  ^                    #digits
      ^                  # a literal '.'
        ^                # anything OTHER THAN a '.'
            ^            # literal '.'
               ^         # anything OTHER THAN a '.'
                     ^   # end of line
```

Comment: I see people use cool regexes and I think maybe I should learn them. I add them to the ever-growing things I should know. Then in future when I need to use regex, I google and then go back to my non-regex-knowing self. Someday, and that day may never come, I will lean regexes!

Comment: Keep looking at examples and one day it will be super natural. This site is a great resource: https://www.rexegg.com

Comment: @lllrnr101 regex is a very sharp double edged sword. I would consider myself pretty proficient in regex, but if possible, I try to make my code readable by people who aren't.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you can split the string by the separator '-', and then join the last two indices. Like so:

```py
txt = "string-anotherstring-15.1R7-S8.1"

x = txt.split("-")

y = "".join(x[-2:])

print(y)  # outputs 15.1R7S8.1
```